# In Selenium how to handle a new window?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am writing a selenium script to login and create new mail, send it and logout. But when I click on New mail button, it opens a new window. In selenium how I can handle this. I am new to selenium. Please explain in detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle mutliple windows in selenium webdriver ,need to switch from second to third window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455402/how-to-handle-mutliple-windows-in-selenium-webdriver-need-to-switch-from-second)

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code, you have to use getWindowHandles- I hope it helps, Let me know in case you get stuck anywhere else -

```
 @Test
        public void multipleWindows() {
            driver.get(URL+"/windows");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".example a")).click();
            Object[] allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray();
            driver.switchTo().window(allWindows[0].toString());
            Assert.assertNotEquals(driver.getTitle(), "New Window");
            driver.switchTo().window(allWindows[1].toString());
            Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "New Window");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How to get Window Handle:
          **String handle = driver.getWindowHandle();**
If there are multiple window gets opened when you click on any link,button etc... then to get "window Handle" of each window -
          **Set windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();**

**"getWindowHandles()"** : method return window handle (unique id for each opened window) so that the return type is set. Because set will not contain duplicate elements so here getWindowHandles return unique id/window handles for each winodw and stored in Set.

**How to switch to correct / appropriate window:**
     Basically there are two ways to switch to appropriate window.

1. By using windowName
        driver.switchTo().window( "windowName" );
       **OR**
2. To get current/parent/default window handle:

   ```
   String handle = driver.getWindowHandle();
   driver.switchTo().window( handle  );
   OR
   Set < String > windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

   for(String handle : windowHandles )
    {
        driver.swicthTo().window( handle ); 
   }
   ```

[**Example of Handling Multiple Windows In Selenium**](http://avinashpandeblogsonseleniumautomation.blogspot.com/2018/08/handling-multiple-windows-in-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it is very easy to understand.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/popup.php");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p/a")).click();

// return the parent window name as a String
 String parentWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


// Pass a window handle to the other window
for(String childWindow: driver.getWindowHandles())
    {
      System.out.println("Switch to child window");

      //switch to child window
      driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);

      //find an element and print text of it 
    WebElement textLabel=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/h2"));
     System.out.println(" text:  "+textLabel.getText());
     driver.close();
            }
     System.out.println("Get back to parent window");

      //switch to Parent window
      driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);

     //find an element and print text of it 
     WebElement logotext=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/h2"));
       System.out.println("text: "+logotext.getText());
       driver.close();
        }
```